# How to standardize pandas timeseries data according to n-th previous day's mean and variance?

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

For example, given data that contains readings taken every second, how do we normalize each row of data according to the mean and standard deviation of the previous day's data?

Assume we have the exact (pandas) timestamp of each row in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Offering up this answer because I was stuck on this problem for awhile and couldnt find any better (and efficient) solutions online.

Assuming that the timestamps are the index of the data:

```
standardize_offset = 1  # Standardize based off data from 1 day prior

data.index.rename('time', inplace=True)
tmp = data.reset_index()
year_day = tmp.set_index([tmp.time.dt.year, tmp.time.dt.dayofyear - standardize_offset])
groupby = tmp.groupby([tmp.time.dt.year, tmp.time.dt.dayofyear])

mean = groupby.mean()
year_day_mean = mean[mean.index.isin(year_day.index)] # Offset above causes index mismatch

std = groupby.std()
year_day_std = std[std.index.isin(year_day.index)]

standardized = ((year_day - year_day_mean) / year_day_std)
standardized = standardized.reset_index(drop=True)
standardized.loc[:, 'time'] = tmp.time # Time will be all NA values
result = standardized.set_index('time')
```